# startActivityForResult not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to select a pdf file from my phone's internal storage using Intents. After calling startActivityForResult an app chooser pops up. A strange thing is happening in the background. Whenever the chooser pops up, the current activity from where I called the intent automatically goes back to previous activity (the chooser remains) and after selecting the pdf file nothing happens and the app stays to that previous activity.

```
    public class Download_pdf extends AppCompatActivity{ 

            @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam_tab);
}
            @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("file/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    }
            }

            @Override
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                    if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            //upload pdf file
               Uri uri = data.getData();
               StorageReference filepath=storageRef.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask=filepath.putFile(uri);
                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               //File uploaded
            }
    }
```

This code was working perfectly before but suddenly its not working anymore. I am not sure what happened. Please help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` anywhere?

Comment: @DavidWasser Nowhere!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have updated the code.

Comment: You should add ldebug logging in the lifecycle methods like `onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` to see what methods are being called when. You should also check your logcat to see if your app or Android has logged any strangeness.

Comment: Please read the link above. Your current code has many compiler errors. The most important one is because methods must be inside a class.

Comment: I have updated the code. I don't think anything more is relevant here. Hope it helps! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirement add return at method `onOptionsItemSelected`

Sample

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);

            Toast.makeText(this, "select file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```